# What are the correct html5 element for this scenario?

Tags: html

I am brand new to html, so struggling a bit with new html5 elements.

I have 2 scenarios where I can't decide if I should be using `article` or `section`.

#### Scenario 1:

I have a home page, which contains lots of different sections (by this I don't necessarily mean html sections). To give an example, 1 part of the home page contains reasons to use my company/website - it also has a `header`.

This is displayed on the home page, but then also on many other pages in the sidebar. If I understand correctly this would fall under `article`, but I'm not entirely sure.

#### Scenario 2:

I have a frequently asked questions page. Each question has an answer, and a number of questions may be grouped under a specific topic.

So, is each topic a `section`, and each question/answer an `article`? Also is the question a `header` to the article?

Any help and advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "brand new to css, so struggling a bit with new html5 elements" What has CSS to do with the semantics of HTML?

Comment: There's a detailed overview of what these elements do in the spec: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#outlines Google for "html5 document outline" for some more beginner-level tutorials.

Comment: @feeela - I did say I was brand new!

Comment: This question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion (and maybe speculations about *possible* impact on some processing e.g. in search engine). The choice is a matter of authoring style and personal preferences.

Comment: Stick with your own interpretation. It all looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the FAQ, I would suggest to use `section` for each topic (including a headline) a description list `dl` with a `dt` for each question and one or more answers, each wrapped in it's own `dd`. You could also omit the `section`s and use nested description lists.

The use of `article` does not make sense here, as of the spec. Think of the `article` element for use cases like blog articles.

I don't understand your first scenario.

Answer (score 1):

**Section tag**

The  tag defines sections in a document. Such as chapters, headers, footers, or any other sections of the document.

**Article tag**

The  tag specifies independent, self-contained content.

An article should make sense on its own and it should be possible to distribute it independently from the rest of the site.

Potential sources for the  element:

- Forum post
- Blog post
- News story
- Comment

**General comment**

What you use is still entirely up to you. Altho you have to keep in mind that not all browsers support all the tags that are included in HTML5. For example, the  tag will work in all the recent browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE9). Many people still use an older version of Internet Explorer (IE8 or IE7 or IE6), which means this tag will not be know by those older browsers.

It's not all that bad, because there is always a solution to let it work in all the browsers, for example you can use the [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) script.

The browsers that don't know the  tag or any other tag from HTML5 treat them as normal inline elements. so you should include the following css rule:

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }
```

Hope this helps a bit :-)

Comment: Thanks - I already have above but would be useful for others looking for same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, an `article` is used for a self-contained document that does not need extra context to be understood. A `section` is a part of a page that is meaningless outside that page.

On your homepage, it looks like your sections could very well be html sections. In your other pages you probably want to make them sections as well, and not articles. If they are just small items you may just want to wrap them in a div in the sidebar and not give them any specific semantic meaning at all.

On your FAQ page, I would say that each question/answer is an `article` (you could imagine them being separate articles in an RSS feed for example). The topics are not really an `article` or a `section`, I don't think they need any specific semantic meaning so you can just group them in a div for layout. The question is not a header to the article, a header is used for a page header that may contain navigation etc. Your question is probably just a a head**ing** (`h1`/`h2`/`h3` etc).

Don't overuse html5 elements by trying to make any block element into a section or article, only use them when there is a real semantic purpose. Page layout should just be done with good old `div`'s.

There is a good article explaining the differences more in depth [over here](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2010/html5-articles-and-sections-whats-the-difference/).

Comment: "A section is part of a page that is meaningless outside that page". This is not the case with the example I gave as it stands alone in the sidebar too.

Comment: Imagine the item in your sidebar completely outside the context of your website. If the text still makes sense without the rest of your site, then it could be an article.

Comment: Got you! If this is the case, none of the scenarios would be atricles as the FAQ's would also be written in the context of the website.

Comment: That could be true, I don't know what the FAQ or the rest of your website is about. If they are about the website, then you're probably right. If they are about the company, they would probably also make sense outside of the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a `section` should be a sub-node of an `article`.

The [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element) says (emphasis by me):

> The article element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and **that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable**, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

So when it would make sense to publish the text elsewhere without giving it any context, you would make it an article.

**Scenario 1**
When the text is meant to appear on different pages of your website, it seems to fulfill this condition.

**Scenario 2**
Usually, each FAQ question/answer pair is about an individual topic and makes sense on its own, so they would be an article. But when your questions are structured in a way that they only make sense when reading them one after another, you would make them sections.

By the way: This answer would be a section, because it doesn't make sense without reading your question. Together, they would form an article.